# Loading KMZ file in an HTTPS website using Google Maps API v3 but the image overlays that the KMZ file has are being called through HTTP by google

Tags: google-maps-api-3, https, internet-explorer-8

As the title says, I have a KMZ file that is being loaded well in Google Maps API V3 but the images found in the KMZ file are being called through HTTP but the site I have is HTTPS.

The API script is being called through HTTPS and even the KMZ Url is an HTTPS link. But then when the API calls the image files found in the KMZ file, it calls an HTTP link which is the below: 
`http://maps.google.com/mapsatt?id=xxxxxxxxxx&f=files/xxxxxx.png&token=`

This is causing warnings of unsecured content in browsers and is preventing people with IE8 to view to the google map. Is there a solution to this issue because all I can think of so far is using KML files to specify the URLs myself.

Comment: That is one hell of a good question, and your description points to a hardcoded http protocol in the library. You might want to submit an issue to the [google maps api v3 issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for noting this. This should now work with https images. Please comment if this is not the case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Elwinar - Technically there was no question, but I think this answer does about as good a job as answering the issue noted in the original post as possible.  that said, just to be more clear: I work at Google, I submitted this issue to our engineers, a fix has been pushed out, and images should now be requested over HTTPS.